# tee results in a null file

Tags: apache2, sudo, awk, tee

I try to change Apache configuration with this:

```
sudo awk '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub("None", "All",$0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf | sudo tee /etc/apache2/apache2.conf > /dev/null
```

After this `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is empty. If I change the destination file to `~/apache2.conf` for example, the output is correct.

Why?

Comment: What does `awk '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub("None", "All",$0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` output? You do not need sudo before `awk`.

Comment: @Pilot6 It outputs the configuration file with the correct modification.

Comment: You are referencing the same file twice in the pipeline, `tee` will overwrite the file before `awk` gets to it. Either use a temporary file or use `sponge` from `moreutils`. If you are using a recent version of GNU awk, it has an [-i inplace argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace)

Comment: Thor is correct. Or use `sed -i`

Comment: @Thor make it an answer please :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: right :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing the same file twice in the pipeline, `tee` will overwrite the file before `awk` gets to it. Either use a temporary file or use `sponge` from *moreutils*.

Recent versions of GNU awk, 4.1.1, have a [`-i inplace` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/1331399) which simulates editing file in-place:

Comment: Another (uglier) way to do this, in case someone can't use `sponge` for any reason is to redirect the processed file to `tee` using a command substitution: `<<<"$(sudo awk '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub("None", "All",$0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf) sudo tee /etc/apache2/apache2.conf > /dev/null"`. This way the file is read before getting truncated by `tee` (although a trailing newline in the original file will be "eat" by to the command substitution).

Answer (score 1):

That your `awk`/`tee` adventure does not work reliably, which has already been said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/663860/367165). **;)**

You could try another way:

*<sub>drum-roll</sub>*

### Use the power of `perl`!

*<sup>again drum-roll</sup>*

```
sudo perl -i.bak -0777pe 's/(<Directory \/var\/www\/>([^<].*\n)*.*AllowOverride\s)None/$1All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

- `-i.bak`

  in-place edit and create a backup `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf.bak`
- `-0777`

  slurps the whole file at once

---

#### Example

*Input file*

`cat foo`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    foo bar
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www1/>
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

*The command*

```
perl -i.bak -0777pe 's/(<Directory \/var\/www\/>([^<].*\n)*.*AllowOverride\s)None/$1All/' foo
```

*The content in the file after starting the command*

`cat foo`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    foo bar
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www1/>
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```